# "Вести дорогу" (в контексте) - можно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Кроме того, роды дома – это ведь ещё и "духовное" акушерство, то есть
>   с вами рядом **человек, который ведёт вас всю эту долгую и трудную
>   дорогу** – практически с начала беременности до окончания грудного
>   вскармливания.

Comment: Вести всю дорогу (=на протяжении всего пути; можно с приделанными к нему эпитетами) - можно. Можно ли к "дороге" из этого выражения добавлять прилагательные - вопрос вкуса. Вряд ли это ошибка, скорее, неэстетичная буквализация устойчивого сочетания "всю дорогу", в котором дорога абстрактна. Типичнее "всю дорогу" клевать носом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Как вариант:**

Кроме того, роды дома – это ведь ещё и "духовное" акушерство, **то есть человек находится рядом с вами всю эту долгую и трудную дорогу** – практически с начала беременности до окончания грудного вскармливания.

***Вести всю дорогу*** кажется стилистической неточностью, так как в данном случае это выражение может восприниматься **в прямом значении.**

Обычно же всю дорогу что-то делают, например: Всю долгую дорогу она неотступно думала о Федосе Платоновиче, . [Борис Васильев. Дом, который построил Дед (1990-2000)] .

Ответ исправлен.

Comment: А где Ваш вариант правки? Что шероховато - это ясно, потому и вопрос.

Comment: А что некорректного, если сама она не могла или не хотела куда-то добраться? Он - пёс-поводырь, конвоир, духовный пастырь, Глонасс или компас.